# Can't find the path!

Tags: iphone, path, filesystems

I'm currently developing an collage application for iPhone and I've now at the point of saving the image and I therefore need the correct path so that the images shows in your image library.

Does anyone know the address to the path?

BR,
drisse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write to that directly, you have to have an in-memory UIImage and then call the method to send it to the library using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() (a normal function defined in UIKit).

You can pass arguments to be notified when the save completes (which you might want to put up an indicator for) but you don't have to use them (pass in nil).

Comment: Note to whoever voted me up:  I had a really awesome answer before, to a question they were not asking!  So I replaced it with this more boring, but correct, one.

Comment: And, I have since re-posted that answer under a specific question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone