# How to access the iPhone Library folder programmatically

Tags: iphone, directory

I heard in [this TUAW Article](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/04/25/voices-that-matter-iphone-five-iphone-app-design-mistakes/) that iPhone apps should stop using the Documents folder to store files.  Instead they should use the library folder.  How do you access the Library folder to store files to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should also be noted that only the Documents directory and the Library/Preferences directory are guaranteed to be maintained when you update your application. So you should be careful that anything not placed in the Documents directory is something that can easily be recreated without the user losing any data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `NSLibraryDirectory` constant instead of the `NSDocumentDirectory` constant when you call  `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. You would only have to worry about this if you actually do plan on writing an application that allows users to manage documents.

Comment: I updated the community wiki for iPhone writable directories here to reflect use of NSLibraryDirectory:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone/1567147#1567147