# How to resolve the error deny write-File-Data?

Tags: ipad, sqlite

getting error like deny Write-File-Data While Adding the data into Sqlite. I am running my application on simulator the sqlite is working fine .but when I am running it on device it is throughing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are writing to a file path that is within the device sandbox area.  The simulator doesn't have this restriction.  See these SO answers:

1. [why can I write on simulator and not on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532998/why-does-my-data-successfully-write-to-a-file-on-the-iphone-simulator-but-not-m/3533150#3533150)
2. [how can I get a writable path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone/1567147#1567147)