# Data getting overwritten : Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am trying to save a random number with current date in core data. But the number is getting over written. Here is my code :

```
func saveRandNumbers (number : Int){

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let date = Date();

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "RandNumbers", in: managedContext);

        let randNumbers = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto : managedContext);

        randNumbers.setValue(number , forKeyPath : "randNumber");
        randNumbers.setValue(date , forKeyPath : "time");

        do{
            try managedContext.save()
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not save\(error)");
        }
    }
```

This is how I am testing it for demo. In `viewDidLoad()`

I call that function with two diff values :

```
saveRandNumbers (number : 3)
saveRandNumbers (number : 4)
```

Code to fetch the data :

```
func fetchRandNumbers (){

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContect = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName : "RandNumbers")

        do{
            RandNumbers = try managedContect.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("Result :\(RandNumbers)")
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch \(error)");
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
[<RandNumbers: 0x608000099690> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p1> ; data: <fault>), <RandNumbers: 0x60800009a400> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p2> ; data: <fault>), <RandNumbers: 0x60800009ac70> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p3> ; data: <fault>), <RandNumbers: 0x60800009acc0> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p4> ; data: <fault>), <RandNumbers: 0x60800009adb0> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p5> ; data: <fault>), <RandNumbers: 0x60000009d470> (entity: RandNumbers; id: 0xd000000000180000 <x-coredata://B35EDED6-9C24-45E7-8F05-D2CB5F5FE4BA/RandNumbers/p6> ; data: {
    randNumber = 4;
    time = nil;
})]
```

And when i print the result i only get 2nd value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check in your documents directory....?

Comment: Where is the code that retrieves the values?  You have only shown the code that saves the number

Comment: @anilkukdeja how ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Updated.

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525694/where-to-store-the-core-data-file

Comment: What is the output of the print in the fetch?  It should print a single value which is an array.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes. Check the updated ques please.

Comment: Right; you got an array of your results. You need to access the elements of that array to get all of the numbers you have saved.

Comment: @Paulw11 But it is showing only the last one, here it is 4 ?

Comment: The others are faults; when you access one of the properties the actual object will be fetched from the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fetched an array of results; you need to iterate through this array to access each individual item.  When you print the array, the objects are faults; placeholder objects that will be replaced with the actual object when you access it.

func fetchRandNumbers (){

```
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContect = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<RandNumbers> = RandNumbers.fetchRequest()

    do{
        let randNumbers = try managedContect.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for randNumber in randNumbers {
            print("random number \(randNumber.number) was saved at \(randNumber.date)")
        }
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Could not fetch \(error)");
    }

}
```

Comment: Getting this : Value of type 'NSMAnagedObject' has no member 'randNumber'

Comment: Its not working. Why you have user RandNumbers.fetchRequest() ? RandNumbers is a var of NSManagedObject type to store the fetched values.

Comment: `RandNumbers` should not be a variable; variables start with lower case letters.  Classes start with upper case letters.  Core Data automatically creates classes for each of your managed object entities.  Using these saves you have having to do all of that messing around with `setValue`.  Change your property name so that it isn't hiding the class.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Working fine now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your `fetchedResults` and print each `randNumber`:

```
RandNumbers = try managedContect.fetch(fetchRequest)
for randNumber in RandNumbers {
    print(randNumber)
}
```

Comment: I need to get those values which i have save as randNumber and time