# Is it possible to prevent a file being renamed in the iTunes File Sharing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, itunes, file-sharing, file-rename

I  have an app which uses a sqlite db, saving it in the Documents directory.

Moreover it allows users to create a csv file from the db and send it via email. This .csv file is also saved in the Documents dir.

I would enable the iTunes File Sharing, so users can also save these files on pc/mac (maybe in the future my app could also read the files added by the users).

I read that users can remove, save, add and rename files via iTunes File Sharing, but I noticed that I didn't succeed in removing my app files via iTunes File Sharing, I can only save/add and rename them.

If the remove isn't possible, this is good for my app, but the user can still rename the .sqlite file.

Is there a way to prevent a file being renamed in the iTunes File Sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the sqlite file from iTunes File sharing by starting the filename with a dot (.)

http://blog.saers.com/archives/2010/06/28/hiding-files-from-itunes-file-sharing/

alternatively see the Library directory here

[How can I get a writable path on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone/1567147#1567147)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is normally possible to remove a file via iTunes File sharing (obviously if it is enabled)? I ask this because I can save/add/rename a file, but I can't remove it, and I wanted to know if this is the normal behavior or if it is possible to remove a file in some way.

Comment: I haven't tried to remove files before. I don't have a way to check that right now either :(