# Write to iPhone file system Access Denied

Tags: iphone, filesystems

When I try to use System.IO to write a text file to iPhone, it shows error Access to path "/xxx/xxx" denied. How can I solve it?

Comment: This is a very broad question, please add some code or specify _how_ you are trying to write the file, and where.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 1):

This is might because yo try to access some restricted path such as call logs.. If you are sure that it is not a restricted file, then you can use `system('chmod 777 /path/')` to change the rights.