# Objective C - Cannot read file in Directory of Document or Cache in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, document

In my work, I just want to read a downloaded PDF in iphone device

At first, I tried to use the "bundleRoot" directory, it is work in simulator but not on device. Now, I just test in simulator for Directory of Document or Cache.

[How can I get a writable path on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone)

After I read the above topic,

I have tried using Directory of Document or Cache.

Here is my code in finding the writable path

/******************************************************************************/

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error;

if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}


NSString *path_to_file = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testing6.pdf"];
```

/******************************************************************************/

I can find the downloaded file and get the size in this directory,but I cannot read the file by using the following code :

```
            pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
    CGPDFPageRetain(page);

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
```

The return pageRect.size.width is 0

After I print out the download and retrieve file path also are :

/Users/ITDEV/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/806ED359-70F8-4C07-996F-6AFC959B3FC7/Library/Caches/testing6.pdf

Anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all other answers won't work then try using NSBundle as below:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfilename" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSLog("path : %@",path);
```

Same problem i faced and i found that my plist file was not in Documents directory but instead it shows me path to my app and then it shows    MYAppName.app/myPlist.plist file. This  means that the app file includes my plist file in its own bundle i.e. MainBundle.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have tried this way(Use Bundle) before too. It is work in simulator perfectly but not on device. Someone said the Bundle are not writable in device. is that true?

Comment: I believe that when files are in bundle they will not be writable. But I am not sure.

Comment: So I cannot save the pdf file into device's bundle T_T

Comment: No you cannot save in MainBundle. But you can save in Document's Directory which is the actual place where resources should be placed.

Comment: I am using the Document Directory, but I cannot retrieve the downloaded file programmatically, even if load it into a webview, I am fail to do this.

Is there any permission setting in this folder?

Comment: I think I am. I use the same path to save and load the file.

   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0]

NSString *path_to_file = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testing6.pdf"];

I get the path by above code

I can save the file correctly.

but is it right path to retrieve the file too?

Comment: https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF  here is the simple create and save, and read example of PDF. Please go through this example on GitHub.

Comment: the retrieving file path format must like as follow :

    NSURL *path_to_file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];

which can be different from  "writetofile" path.

It wasted me 2 days time T_T

Answer (score 0):

**You can read the file in UIWebView.**

**And By using below code you can open the file.**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error;

if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}


NSString *path_to_file = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testing6.pdf"];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path_to_file];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[YourWebViewName loadRequest:request];
```

**Don't Forget to connect the `IBOutlet` of your webview with nib file's UIWebview.**

Comment: thanks for reply. I have used this way to view PDF in my apps before but we think that is not good enough. We want to store a small size PDF into apps before viewing.

Comment: Do You have the url of that pdf file from where you want to store in your application path.

Comment: YES! I can download the PDF to Iphone document directory from url perfectly!

But I cannot open it programmatically, I can open the pdf manually if I go to the folder directly.