# iOS app content update

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app which will display some text and images offline. How can I do this? Shall I have multiple HTML pages in the app which would be displayed on the browser? This approach wouldn't give the feeling of a premium app.

I can have static content hard-coded within the app which users can browse through. This would definitely give the impression of a premium app.

However the admin can update the app and all the other users are supposed to be notified of the same. I did some research and found that this can be done using TestFlight. But my app is not in beta stage.

Any idea of how this can be implemented?

Comment: Don't make glorified web apps, they will be rejected.  Learn Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You have the ability to save images and text files onto the device. e.g.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:documentsDirectory];
```

`NSDocumentDirectory` is where you can store your downloaded files permanently.
`NSCachesDirectory` is where you can store files that can go away at any time, and you can just recreate them as needed.

There are other types of storage, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone)

So go ahead and download the text and image files from your server and display them to the user, and this will work offline. Of course, the user has to be online at some point to download them in the first place.