# Create a writable folder on iOS device

Tags: ios

How does one create a read/write folder on the same level as the Documents directory? Is there a way to set the directory used in file sharing on iOS between iTunes and an app, or is it hard coded to the Documents directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a non-jailbroken device, you cannot create a read/write folder on the same level as the Documents directory. Additionally, there is not way to change the directory used in file sharing.

If you need to create files and want to keep them away from file sharing, there are other writable directories that can be used. This [SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone/1567147#1567147) deals with that quite well.

Comment: So every file written to the documents directory, even subfolders will be accessible in the app's file sharing window in iTunes, or is it possible to hide files, such as private files for the app?

Comment: Put them in another folder, instead of the documents folder.

Comment: To date, iTunes does not show any "dot" files in the Documents directory. If you name a file or folder with a leading dot in the name, iTunes will not show that to the user.

Comment: Nice find but I think using the Library Directory removes hard coded naming.