# iOS stream audio from authenticated URL

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, oauth-2.0, avplayer

I want to stream audio file from a source that needs OAuth2 authentication, this is my code, but it is not working.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:req.URL];
        [player play];
```

Can you please help?

Comment: did you try like this?  [req addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

Comment: Tried it now, not working

Comment: @Wikiboo are u able to solve ur issue regarding Streaming audio from google drive..

Comment: any updates on this question? Thank you

Comment: No updates, did not resolve it...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're adding your authentication token as an HTTP header, but then making a request using only the URL (and headers are not included in the URL).

I need to do a similar thing in my app, but it doesn't look like it's possible to interfere with AVPlayer's network request (at least, not with a public API).  So now I'm looking at either requesting the file myself using NSURLSession (which means no streaming - gotta wait for the whole file, or else do some complicated processing to hand it off to an audio player in chunks), or else fudge the web service to accept my parameter as a query parameter instead of as an HTTP header.

This question also has some potential work-arounds: [Send headers with AVPlayer request in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456130/send-headers-with-avplayer-request-in-ios)

Comment: why there is no streaming in case of NSUrlSession ?