# Getting Timed Metadata in Swift ios 8 From M3U8 Streaming Video

Tags: swift, ios8, metadata, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to duplicate this https://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/ in swift.

Here is a video of Jake's code in action...

[Objective C Timed Metadat in HLS stream](https://vimeo.com/16455248)

Here is an additional link to something similar...

http://cloudfields.net/blog/metadata-audiostream-mpmovieplayercontroller/

When my video is playing timed metadata should update a button to redirect to a specific youtube url in a webview when clicked.  My video is roughly 15 min long and has 6 timed metadata urls.

I can't find any code or documentation anywhere on how to achieve this in Swift.  I've managed to convert Jake's Objective C code for his Notification call.

```
// Register for meta-data notifications
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [center addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(metadataUpdate:)
           name:MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification
         object:nil];
```

to Swift Code

```
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: "metadataUpdated",
            name: MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification,
            object: nil)
```

Jake's Function

```
Actor *actor = [[Actor alloc] init];

 if ([player timedMetadata]!=nil && [[player timedMetadata] count] > 0) {
for (MPTimedMetadata *metadata in [player timedMetadata]) {
if ([[metadata.allMetadata valueForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"TPE1"]) {
        [actor setName:[metadata.allMetadata objectForKey:@"value"]];
    }
    if ([[metadata.allMetadata valueForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"WXXX"]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[metadata.allMetadata objectForKey:@"value"]];
        [actor setProfileURL:url];
    }
  }
}

// display some UI element for the user to interact with
```

to Swift

```
func metadataUpdated (notification: NSNotification!) {

    if moviePlayer?.timedMetadata != nil && moviePlayer?.timedMetadata.count > 0 {


        for MPTimedMetadata in [moviePlayer?.timedMetadata] {

            if MPTimedMetadata?.description  == ("TPE1") {

                let name = ("value")

            }

            if MPTimedMetadata?.description  == ("WXXX") {

                var url = NSURL.observeValueForKeyPath("value")

            }
        } 
}
println("Things are kind of working")
}
}
```

For the life of me though I cant figure out how to turn the metadata into any actionable code.  I really need to create a button that redirects to the URL carried in the metadata, but can't convert it to a String. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is what i have so far.

```
import UIKit

import MediaPlayer



class ViewController: UIViewController {


var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?


var youtube = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let url = NSURL(string: "http://path/to/video.m3u8")



    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)



    if let player = moviePlayer {



        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        player.view.sizeToFit()

        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.None





        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming

        //player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One





        player.play()



        self.view.addSubview(player.view)



        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(

            self,

            selector: "metadataUpdated:",

            name: MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification,

            object: nil)



    }

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



func metadataUpdated (notification: NSNotification!) {






    if moviePlayer?.timedMetadata != nil && moviePlayer?.timedMetadata.count > 0 {


        for MPTimedMetadata in [moviePlayer?.timedMetadata] {

            if MPTimedMetadata?.description  == ("TPE1") {

                let name = ("value")



            }

            if MPTimedMetadata?.description  == ("WXXX") {

                var url = NSURL.observeValueForKeyPath("value")



            }


        }


}
println("Things are kind of working")


}


}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue, are you having trouble parsing the URL or converting the URL to a string?

Comment: I was having a problem converting to a string.  Thanks for asking.  Made me remember to post my results.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So I got this to work, but ended up ditch MPMovieController opting for AVPlayer.  Here is my code, and the link to another post that helped me get it functional.

[Timed Metadata with AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955125/timed-metadata-with-avplayer)

```
import UIKit

import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation

var youtubeRequest: NSURLRequest! = nil
var player : AVPlayer? = nil

var url:NSString!


class ViewController: UIViewController {


var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?
var movieItem: AVPlayerItem!
var Player: AVPlayer!

var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem!

var youtubeRequest: NSURLRequest! = nil

@IBOutlet var playButtonOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func playButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {player?.play()
    playButtonOutlet.enabled = false

}

@IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!
@IBAction func loadURL(sender: AnyObject) {player?.pause()
    playButtonOutlet.enabled = true
}
@IBOutlet var urlButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    urlButton.enabled = false

    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://path/to/video.m3u8")
    playButtonOutlet.enabled = false

    movieItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://path/to/video.m3u8"))
    movieItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: nil, context: nil)
    Player = AVPlayer(playerItem: movieItem)

    var metaArray: Array<Any> = [moviePlayer?.timedMetadata]







    asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoURL) as? AVAsset
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://path/to/video.m3u8"))
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: nil, context: nil)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "presentationSize", options: nil, context: nil)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)



    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer!.frame = videoView.bounds

    videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)

    player!.play()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(

        self,

        selector: "rotated",

        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification,

        object: nil)


}

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void {

        if keyPath != "timedMetadata" { return }

        var data: AVPlayerItem = object as AVPlayerItem

        var urlError = false

        for item in data.timedMetadata as [AVMetadataItem] {

            println(item.stringValue)
            var metaArray: Array<Any> = [playerItem?.timedMetadata]
            println("Total objects in array \(metaArray[0])")


            var data = item.stringValue

          url = NSString(string: data) as NSString!



            if url != nil {

             urlButton.enabled = true

                println("The url is \(url)")




            } else {

                urlError = true

            }


            var urlRedirect = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(url)")


            println("The url is \(urlRedirect)")

        }


    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

func rotated()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        playerLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)
        playerLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)

        println("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        playerLayer!.frame = videoView.bounds

        println("portraight")
    }

 }


}
```

Comment: A few updates for Swift 3: `avplayeritem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: [], context: nil)` and `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535465/how-to-fetch-resolution-supported-by-video-m38u-file-url-in-swift