# How to add signed cookies in URL of streaming video?

Tags: swift, cookies, video-streaming

```
//MARK:- setting player
fileprivate func setPlayRemoteUrl() {
    if playUrl.isEmpty { return }
    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: playUrl)!)

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer?.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
}
```

How to add signed cookies in URL of streaming video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send headers with AVPlayer request in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456130/send-headers-with-avplayer-request-in-ios)

Comment: JWPlayer supports cookies: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/embedding/features/#custom-asset-options