# How to pass HTTP Basic Authentication to AVAudioPlayer in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, avaudioplayer

I'm attempting to load a remote MP3 through the `AVAudioPlayer` in Swift 4. So far, everything is working just great.

Now, I'm attempting to load our secure URL, which uses Basic Authentication for the URL.

What I have is this:

```
    let username = "my_username"
    let password = "my_password"
    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    // create the request
    let url = URL(string: "https://audio.my_domain.com/\(hashKey)/my_file.mp3")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    guard let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: request) else {
        self.endPlayback()
        return
    }
```

Of course the error that I get is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'URLRequest' to expected argument type
>   'URL'

I'm not surprised by this as a `URL` is not a `URLRequest` object. So, my question is. How can I load the URL stream into the `AVAudioPlayer` using Basic HTTP Authentication?

I can't seem to find anywhere that does this. Perhaps this isn't possible?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [AVAudioPlayer is not meant to play audio over the network](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer):

> Use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O latency.

You'll want to either download the complete mp3 file into either a local file or a `Data` object before playing, or use an [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) instead (which is designed to be able to play audio over the network).

In order to create an `AVPlayer`, that plays audio over the network must first create an [`AVURLAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset):

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/file.mp3")!)
```

There are at least two ways to use basic authentication with an `AVURLAsset`:

1. [Use the AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23713028/3476191) to set a custom header.  Note that this key is undocumented.
2. Add the credential to the shared [`URLCredentialStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcredentialstorage):

   ```
   let credential = URLCredential(
       user: "username",
       password: "password", 
       persistence: .forSession
   )
   let protectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace(
       host: "example.com",
       port: 443,
       protocol: "https",
       realm: nil,
       authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic
   )
   URLCredentialStorage.shared.setDefaultCredential(credential, for: protectionSpace)
   ```

You can then create an [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/AVPlayerItem) with your asset, and finally an AVPlayer:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will take a look today and see how this works. Appreciate your response