# Add header to media url in AVKit VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, swiftui, avkit

I want to play video media file from url in my application but its required to add authorization token in header. Is there any way handle that? I using SwiftUI and support iOS 14 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVPlayerItem` constructor instead of the url string constructor, and follow the steps to add headers to an AVPlayerItem laid out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54068128/998335).