# Saving contents of NSMutableArray containing custom class objects

Tags: object, nsmutablearray, save

I have a custom class "Bookmark" which contains an `NSString`.  I use a `NSMutableArray` to store instances of this class thus making a bookmark list which I display in a `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCell` prototype.

Would someone please give some advice/example on how to save the instances within the `NSMutableArray` to a file (and perhaps an example how to load them).  I can't get any examples I've searched to work.  I've tried converting the array to `NSData` and using `NSKeyedArchiver` without success.  I've also tried converting to an `NSArray` but can't get it to work.

Within the custom class I've implemented `encodeWithCode` and `initWithCoder`.

I need to save before the app closes and I want to load the list when the app is started.

I'm stuck...  :(

EDIT:  At the request of Ageektrapped, here are the code snippets:

Inside the implementation of my Bookmark class:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder
{
  [encoder encodeObject:self.address forKey:@"Address"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil)
  {
    self.address = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"Address"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

In my MasterViewController

`self.bookmarks` is a `NSMutableArray` containing bookmark objects.  (When the code below is called, there is at least one entry in the bookmarks array.)

```
NSString *docFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject];
NSString *filename = [docFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSLog(@"File : %@", filename);
NSLog(@"Bookmarks : %d", self.bookmarks.count);

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.bookmarks ];
if ([data writeToFile: filename atomically: YES])
{
  NSLog(@"Successful write");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Failed write");
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: method implementations? And the code that saves the array to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what my problem was.
Because I'm debugging on my iPhone device, some folders are not writable. The code I was using was asking for a location in such an area (`NSDocumentationDirectory`):

After finally finding =>
[How can I get a writable path on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone)  I understood my problem and got it working.

What I needed to do was replace:

```
NSString *docFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject];
NSString *filename = [docFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
```

with:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *libFolder = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *filename = [libFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"];
```

I also changed these lines (to be consistent with the example) from:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.bookmarks ];
if ([data writeToFile: filename atomically: YES])
{
  NSLog(@"Successful write");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Failed write");
}
```

to:

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: self.bookmarks toFile: filename];
if (success)
{
  NSLog(@"Successful write");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Failed write");
}
```

.

The code to read the file into the `NSMutableArray` on application startup is:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *libFolder = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *filename = [libFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"];
self.bookmarks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: filename];
```