# saving the UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

this is a follow up from my question yesterday 
my .h is

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *initialBudget;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *expenses;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeSpent;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *incomePerHour;
```

my .m is:

```
- (IBAction)calculateResults:(id)sender {
    double budget = [initialBudget.text doubleValue ];
    double expense = [expenses.text doubleValue];
    double time = [timeSpent.text doubleValue];

    double hourlyIncome = (budget - expense)/time;
   incomePerHour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", hourlyIncome];
}
```

Ive tried using different methods to keep the text saved in the ViewController, when I close the app the text disappears.  Anyone have an idea?  Ive only been studying Objective-C since the beginning of the summer so my apologies for the potential newbie questions.

Comment: Have you connected the IBOutlet.

Comment: Which text do need to save ? and where you need to save ?

Comment: IBOutlets are connected I need to save all of the text

Comment: Save it where? None of your code above does anything related to 'saving' anything.

Comment: "save" is ambiguous.  please describe what you see vs. what you expect to see.  Is it that the text field incomePerHour does not contain a result after the method calculateResults runs?

Comment: Have you done any searching on this subject? There are plenty of examples on using `NSUserDefaults` or other persistence mechanisms to save and restore data.

Comment: It contains a result.  After I exit the Viewcontroller I would like to have the text from the result still in place.

Comment: okay.  there are many places to save.  from variable names, this looks like a dictionary written to a file in NSCachesDirectory.  Look at this SO, but consider NSCachesDirectory as the destination.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone

Comment: For a small amount of data you can use NSUserDefaults - google it and you'll see it only needs a few lines of code. For a larger amount of data -- anything more than a handful of values -- you should look into Core Data.

Comment: THank you, Im looking into NSUserdefaults now

Answer (score 3):

Either save the text/string using [**NSUserDefaults**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or you can use **SQLite** to save/update/insert/retrieve the data.And when displaying it in textfield just retrieve it from sqlite…

Tutorials on sqlite..

1) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

2) http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

**EDIT** :

You can use NSUserDefaults if you're storing small portions of data, while other approaches like coredata and sqlite are good to store bigger amounts of data.

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Save as file is also applicable for OP's case, via `writeToPath` method

Comment: NB, this answer isn't exactly correct: NSUserDefaults stores data permanently to disk, just like Core Data / SQLite. You can terminate the app as much as you like and the data will persist.

Comment: @davidf2281...thanks for the info...yes and one more small correction..i will edit the answer..

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your goal is to update the text of the `incomePerHour` text field with the calculated result of the other text fields.

You need to create a string from the result and update the text field's text property. You really should use an `NSNumberFormatter` setup for currency values.

```
double hourlyIncome = (budget - expense)/time;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(hourlyIncome)];
incomePerHour.text = formattedString;
```

**Update** - it appears that the actual question is about persisting the values between runs of the app. This answer is no longer all that appropriate.

Comment: Ive made the change, I need to know how to save all the outlets so they dont disappear when I close the app

Comment: That's a completely different question. You need to update your question to make that goal clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefault` to save your textField's result.

Try as following -

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  //get and set value to your text field from the userdefault whenever you come from closeing the app..

  double result = [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault]valueForKey:@"INCOME_VALUE"];
  incomePerHour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", result];
}

- (IBAction)calculateResults:(id)sender 
{
    double budget = [initialBudget.text doubleValue ];
    double expense = [expenses.text doubleValue];
    double time = [timeSpent.text doubleValue];

    double hourlyIncome = (budget - expense)/time;
   incomePerHour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", hourlyIncome];

   //set your result's value in the userdefault to access it later....
   [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault]setDouble:hourlyIncome forKey:@"INCOME_VALUE"];
}
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: You need to have a check for there being no value in `NSUserDefaults`. Otherwise this code will put `0.00` in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to save your text is to use NSUSerDefault. Sqlite should be considered if you need structured data saved.