# iOS App file sharing; share and add specific extensions

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing

I have enabled file sharing in my project to allow the user to take out some files from the App. However, I want to prevent the users from adding any files to the App, or limit them to add files with specific extensions.

-Is there anyway to achieve that?

-Anyway to share specific files only? The App using Core data and I can see sqlite files there.

Thanks

Comment: Sharing specific files only can be achieved by saving the files to different directory. This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567134/how-can-i-get-a-writable-path-on-the-iphone)